# How to get only author's last name when cited 2nd time?

Tags: biblatex

In footnote citation I'd like to have the author's full name when cited the 1st time, but only last name when cited the 2nd time. And in bibliography it should be full name again. Any idea how to get this?
It should look like:

```
1 Vgl. Otto, Wilfriede: Verfassungsdebatte und Verfassungen der DDR. Berlin: 2002. S. 145ff.

2 Vgl. Jäger, Manfred: Kultur und Politik in der DDR. 1945-1990. Köln: 1994. S. 12f.

3 vgl. Wilfriede: Verfassungsdebatte und Verfassungen der DDR (wie Anm. 1), S. 13.
```

Would be thankful for help! =)

A friend installed:

```
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%9
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.5 (27/8/17)
%
% This template was downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Version 2.x major modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% This template is based on a template by:
% Steve Gunn (http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/)
% Sunil Patel (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
twoside,
%english, 
ngerman, %for German
onehalfspacing, %singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international character
\usepackage{microtype} %for better typesetting and readability

\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash, labelsep=colon, labelformat=simple]{caption}

\usepackage{wrapfig}



\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default

\usepackage[style=footnote-dw, natbib=true, nopublisher=false, urldate=long, citepages=separate, idembib=false, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}
\makeatother
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{last-first}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  and={u\adddot},
  editor={Hg\adddot},
  editors={Hg\adddot},
  byeditor={hg\adddot\thinspace v\adddotspace},
  thiscite={hier\addcolon\thinspace},
  number={H\adddot},
  }


\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibrevsdnamedelim}{}
\renewcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citerevsdnamedelim}{}


\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\addto\captionsngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}%
  \renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Keine "Schusterjungen"
    \clubpenalty = 10000
    % Keine "Hurenkinder"
    \widowpenalty = 10000 \displaywidowpenalty = 10000


\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \iflistundef{location}
    {\setunit*{\adddot\space}}
    {\setunit*{\adddot\space}}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\addbibresource{Literaturverzeichnis.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography

%\overfullrule=2cm %um anzuzeigen, wo overfull hboxes sind, wieder rausnehmen vor Druck!

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGIN SETTINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\linespread{1.3}
\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3.5cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=.6cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    head=36pt,
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\thesistitle{Titel} % Your thesis title, this is used in the title and abstract, print it elsewhere with \ttitle
\supervisor{Prof. Dr. X} % Your supervisor's name, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \supname
\examiner{Prof. Dr. Y} % Your examiner's name, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \examname
\degree{doctor philosophiae (Dr. phil.)} % Your degree name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \degreename
\author{Name} % Your name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \authorname
\addresses{} % Your address, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \addressname

\subject{} % Your subject area, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \subjectname
\keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \keywordnames
\university{Universität} % Your university's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \univname
\department{Forschungsinstitut} % Your department's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \deptname
\group{} % Your research group's name and URL, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \groupname
\faculty{Fakultät} % Your faculty's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \facname

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages

\pagestyle{plain} % Default to the plain heading style until the thesis style is called for the body content

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

%\vspace*{.05\textheight}
{\scshape\LARGE \univname\par}\vspace{0.4cm} % University name
\large\deptname\\Fakultät\\[1,8cm] % Research group name and department name
\textsc{\Large Dissertation}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type

\HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
{\huge \bfseries \ttitle\par}\vspace{0.4cm}\
\Large Titel % Thesis title
\HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line
 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Autor:}\\
{\authorname}\vspace{0.4cm}\\
\addressname
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Erstgutachter:} \\
{\supname}\\\vspace{0.4cm}
\emph{Zweitgutachterin:} \\
{\examname} 
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]
 
\vfill

\large {Zur Erlangung des akademischen Grades}\\[0.3cm] % University requirement text
\Large\textit{\degreename}\\[1cm]
 
\vfill

% Date
%\includegraphics{Logo} % University/department logo - uncomment to place it
 
\vfill
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   QUOTATION PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\vspace*{0.2\textheight}

%\noindent\enquote{\itshape Text. [\ldots] Text.}\bigbreak

%\hfill Vil\'em Flusser (1993)

%\cleardoublepage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abstract}
\addchaptertocentry{\abstractname} % Add the abstract to the table of contents

\end{abstract}

\cleardoublepage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\begin{acknowledgements}
%\addchaptertocentry{\acknowledgementname} % Add the acknowledgements to the table of contents
%The acknowledgments and the people to thank go here, don't forget to include your project advisor\ldots
%\end{acknowledgements}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LIST OF CONTENTS/FIGURES/TABLES PAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{sloppypar}
\tableofcontents % Prints the main table of contents
\end{sloppypar}
\listoffigures % Prints the list of figures
\listoftables %\listoftables % Prints the list of tables
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABBREVIATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\begin{abbreviations}{ll} % Include a list of abbreviations (a table of two columns)

%\textbf{LAH} & \textbf{L}ist \textbf{A}bbreviations \textbf{H}ere\\
%\textbf{WSF} & \textbf{W}hat (it) \textbf{S}tands \textbf{F}or\\

%\end{abbreviations}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PHYSICAL CONSTANTS/OTHER DEFINITIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



%\begin{constants}{lr@{${}={}$}l} % The list of physical constants is a three column table

% The \SI{}{} command is provided by the siunitx package, see its documentation for instructions on how to use it

%Speed of Light & $c_{0}$ & \SI{2.99792458e8}{\meter\per\second} (exact)\\
%Constant Name & $Symbol$ & $Constant Value$ with units\\

%\end{constants}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SYMBOLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\begin{symbols}{lll} % Include a list of Symbols (a three column table)

%$a$ & distance & \si{\meter} \\
%$P$ & power & \si{\watt} (\si{\joule\per\second}) \\
%Symbol & Name & Unit \\

%\addlinespace % Gap to separate the Roman symbols from the Greek

%$\omega$ & angular frequency & \si{\radian} \\

%\end{symbols}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEDICATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\dedicatory{For/Dedicated to/To my\ldots} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - CHAPTERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering

\pagestyle{thesis} % Return the page headers back to the "thesis" style



\include{Chapters/Einleitung}
\include{Chapters/Chapter1} 
\include{Chapters/Chapter2}
\include{Chapters/Chapter3} 
\include{Chapters/Chapter4}
\include{Chapters/Chapter5}
\include{Chapters/Chapter6}
\include{Chapters/Chapter7}
\include{Chapters/Fazit}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DECLARATION PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{declaration}
\addchaptertocentry{\authorshipname} % Add the declaration to the table of contents
\noindent Ich versichere hiermit, dass ich die vorliegende Arbeit mit dem Titel\\[0.3cm]
{\large \bfseries \ttitle\par}\vspace{0.3cm}
\sloppy \noindent selbstständig verfasst und keine anderen als die angegebenen Hilfsmittel benutzt habe. Die Stellen, die anderen Werken dem Wortlaut oder dem Sinn nach entnommen wurden, habe ich in jedem einzelnen Fall durch die Angabe der Quelle, auch der benutzten Sekundärliteratur, als Entlehnung kenntlich gemacht. Ich bestätige, diese Arbeit weder bisher noch gleichzeitig einer anderen Prüfungsbehörde vorgelegt zu haben.\\[1cm]
 
\noindent Unterschrift:\\
\rule[0.5em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line for the signature
 
\noindent Datum:\\
\rule[0.5em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line to write the date
\end{declaration}

\cleardoublepage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - APPENDICES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following "chapters" are Appendices

% Include the appendices of the thesis as separate files from the Appendices folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the Appendices

%\include{Appendices/AppendixA}
%\include{Appendices/AppendixB}
%\include{Appendices/AppendixC}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\nocite{*}
\setstretch{0.8}
%\onehalfspacing
\setlength\bibitemsep{10pt}


\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title=Literaturverzeichnis]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: This depends a lot on the bibliography/citation package(s) you (want to) load and the style you use. With BibTeX it would appear possible, but quite painful, while with `biblatex` it should be doable (I'm avoiding saying it would be easy with `biblatex`, but at least quite a bit less painful than with BibTeX). Can you tell us a little more about your current setup (in an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and about the output you would like to see?

Comment: see changes above with the info ;-)

Comment: Ah that's a start. Can you please explain in more detail what output you would like to see? It would also be great if you could turn the code posted so far into a compilable example document (it should start with `\documentclass`, should have `\begin{document}...\end{document}`) along with an example `.bib` entry. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864

Comment: so here we go. 
(I'm sorry for all the steps, I am new to LaTex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the block

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{last-first}
```

with

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

`labelname` controls the name format of subsequent citations. If you set that format to `last-first` (or its current equivalent `family-given`) you always get the full name. With the slight modification of the standard `labelname` macro shown above you get only the family name by default, a first name initial or the first name is only added to avoid ambiguities.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=footnote-dw,
  natbib=true,
  nopublisher=false,
  urldate=long,
  citepages=separate,
  idembib=false,
  maxbibnames=99]{biblatex} 

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  and      = {u\adddot},
  editor   = {Hg\adddot},
  editors  = {Hg\adddot},
  byeditor = {hg\adddot\thinspace v\adddotspace},
  thiscite = {hier\addcolon\thinspace},
  number   = {H\adddot},
}

\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibrevsdnamedelim}{}
\renewcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citerevsdnamedelim}{}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[156\psqq]{nussbaum}
ipsum \autocite[379]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[160\psq]{nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Nussbaum: Aristotle’s „De Motu Animalium“ (wie Anm. 1), S. 160 f.]

Comment: Wow! Awesome! Works perfectly! Thank you very much!
One last thing: Do you also know how to replace the comma before the page number with a dot?

Comment: @qu33ristan In all footnotes or only in the first citation?

Comment: would be nice in all footnotes, so at first footnote a dot after the year and a dot after the bracket at the following footnotes =)

Comment: @qu33ristan With a current version of `biblatex` `\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addperiod\space}` should help. If you are using an outdated version of `biblatex`, you may have to try `\renewcommand*\postnotedelim{\addperiod\space}`

Comment: Works perfectly! Seems like you are a real pro! Thank you very much!

Comment: @qu33ristan Glad it works for you. If the answer helped you solve your problem, you may want to consider accepting it (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to show that you consider the question resolved.